Upper Bounding Tensor Products
I am having trouble finding an upper bound for this problem involving tensor multiplication. Given a tensor $T$ with dimensions $n \times n \times n$ and a vector $v$ with dimensions $n \times 1$, I am trying to find a bound for
$$|| T \cdot v^2 ||_2 \leq f(T)||v||^2_2 $$
where $T \cdot v^2 = \sum\limits_{j,k} T_{ijk} v_j v_k$ and $f(T)$ is just some operation on $T$.
I tried expanding the terms and using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, but I can't seem to reduce the last step. Here is my work:
\begin{align*}
    u^2_i &= \left( \sum_{j,k} T_{ijk} v_j v_k \right)^2\\
    ||u|| &= || T \cdot v^2|| = \sqrt{\sum_i \left( \sum_{j,k} T_{ijk} v_j v_k \right)^2}
\end{align*}
With the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
    \left( \sum_i u_i v_i \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_i u^2_i \right) \left(\sum_i  v^2_i  \right)
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
    \left( \sum_i \left( \sum_{j,k} T_{ijk} v_j v_k \right) v_i \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_i \left( \sum_{j,k} T_{ijk} v_j v_k \right)^2 \right) ||v||^2
\end{align*}
Am I missing something? Is it possible to find an upper bound with my form?

Ok, using the triangle inequality, I was able to get an upper bound of $T_\max ||v||^2_1$ where $T_\max$ is the max abs value of $T_{ijk}$. If no one can think of a better upper bound, I might just post my answer

*Missing $n$ in front
